# how to use variable variable names in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the values of some php variables into a bash script in order to set other bash variables.   Basically I need to be able to access the value of a variable - variable name.

the script can find & read the file, find the php variables, but when I try to set them it just hangs.  Here is what I have:

```
variables=(database_user database_password dbase);

paths=(modx_core_path modx_connectors_path modx_manager_path modx_base_path);

for index in "${variables[@]}"; do
index=\$$index
echo $index;
$index="$(grep -oE '\$${!index} = .*;' $config | tail -1 | sed 's/$${!index} = //g;s/;//g')";
done
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: @123, please don't suggest the ABS as a reference; it's rather infamous for showcasing bad practices. [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is a much more up-to-date and actively maintained discussion of indirect variables.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to perform an indirect assignment.

You should get rid of these two lines :

```
index=\$$index
echo $index;
```

By simply writing :

```
echo "${!index}"
```

Which does an indirect expansion cleanly (gives you the value of the variable whose name is contained in variable `index`).

Next, the problematic line is this one:

```
$index="$(grep -oE '\$${!index} = .*;' ... (rest omitted)
```

In Bash, an assignment cannot begin with a `$`.

One way you can perform an indirect assignment is this (after removing the `index` re-assignment as suggested above) :

```
printf -v "$index" "$(grep -oE '\$${!index} = .*;' ... (rest omitted)
```

This uses the `-v` option of `printf`, which causes the value passed as the final argument to be assigned to a variable, the name of which is passed to the `-v` option.

There are other ways of handling indirect assignment/expansions, some with code injection risks, as they use (potentially uncontrolled) data as code.  This is something you may want to research further.

Please note I am assuming the actual `grep` command substitution works (I have not tested).